# Connection between determinantal point process kernel and Hilbert-Schmidt operator kernel

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, analysis, random-matrices

I am wondering about the connection between the kernel which gives the nth correlation function of a determinantal point process and the L^2 Hilbert space for which it uniquely defines an integral operator.

The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinantal_point_process) of a determinantal point process defined from a kernel $K$ is as follows.

> Let $\Lambda$ be a locally compact Polish space and $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $\Lambda .$ Also, consider a measurable function $K: \Lambda^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.
> We say that $X$ is a determinantal point process on $\Lambda$ with kernel $K$ if it is a simple point process on $\Lambda$ with a joint intensity or correlation function (which is the density of its factorial moment measure) given by
> $$
> \rho_{n}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)=\operatorname{det}\left[K\left(x_{i}, x_{j}\right)\right]_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}
> $$
> for every $n \geq 1$ and $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \in \Lambda .$

This definition however says nothing about the relationship between this kernel and the Hilbert space $L^2(\Lambda)$ for which it defines an integral operator by $T: L^2(\Lambda)\to L^2(\Lambda)$ by.

$$T(f)(x)=\int_\Lambda K(x,y) f(y)dy$$

What purpose does the Hilbert space of square-integrable functions $L^2(\Lambda)$ serve when working with determinantal point processes? Why might I be interested in such a bounded linear operator from $L^2(\Lambda)\to L^2(\Lambda)$?

It feels that the $L^2(\Lambda)$ is a separate object from the probability space and polish space over which the point processes is defined and to me, it is unclear why this is relevant.

Comment: If you are writing your question for someone who doesn't know the definition of a *determinantal point process* but is well versed in *simple point processess on Λ with a joint intensity or correlation function* then I'm afraid you've got a very small audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The survey Soshnikov, Alexander. "Determinantal random point fields." Russian Mathematical Surveys 55, no. 5 (2000)   is highly recommended and should clarify the matter for you.

We also tried our best to explain the connection in the book https://yuvalperes.com/zeros-of-gaussian-analytic-functions-and-determinantal-point-processes/   (there is a link to the PDF at that site.)
In particular, if you look at Algorithm 4.2, you will see how the kernel can be used to sample from the point process. This was developed further in
the book:

Kulesza, Alex, and Ben Taskar. "Determinantal point processes for machine learning."  Foundations and Trends® in Machine Learning 5, no. 2–3 (2012): 123-286.

Comment: Thank you very much. My understanding after reading a bit of the resources you linked is that much can be said about determinantal point processes whose kernel is given by Heremitian non-negative locally trace class operators on $L^2(\Lambda)$ however, DPPs defined by this type of kernel are only a subset of the general definition of a DPP. Do DPPs which are not given by the kernels of integral operators commonly appear in the literature?

Comment: My understanding is limited to DPPs governed by Hermitian operators. A more general point of view is in the survey :Borodin, A., Determinantal point processes. In The Oxford Handbook of Random Matrix Theory.   https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1153.pdf